# How do I solve for the elements of the partial derivative of a Hessian matrix?

Tags: taylor-expansion, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

In the paper about Speeded-Up Robust Features, it says that in order to localize points, interpolation of nearby data is needed to find the location in space and scale. This is done by fitting a 3D quadratic. In order to do this, the determinant of the Hessian function H(x, y, sigma) is expressed as a Taylor expansion up to quadratic terms centered at detected location.

[image]

My question is, how do I solve for the elements in the matrices shown? How do I solve for dx, dxx, dxy, etc.? Thank you!

Comment: This WP page might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus